# Passing object as argument in Angular HttpHeaders

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a header object dynamically and pass it to HttpHeaders as argument. It works when using **ng serve** even it shows as error. However, doesn't allow **ng build**. Most solutions involve using JSON.stringify but that isn't working, I've commented and left it in the code for now.

```
getData(url: string, header: object, params: object){
    console.log("header: "+ header)
    //let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(JSON.stringify(header));
    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(header);
    console.log(this.http.get(url));
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: httpHeaders}); 
  }
```

When I try the **JSON.stringify(header)** I get the error below

> Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': '{"x-rapidapi-host"' is not a valid HTTP header field name.

I can't understand why this isn't working since if I try to hardcode the same header in the **httpHeaders** it works fine e.g.

```
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({"x-rapidapi-host": "some value", 
                                   "x-rapidapi-key": "some-value"});
```

Comment: `let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(header);` works fine for me, both for `ng serve` and `ng build`. Can you create a stackblitz reproducing the issue? In any case, using `JSON.stringify` definitely won't work as it's not the format expected by the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define constant outside of the class and not inside

```
const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':  'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'})};
```

And use as follows

```
return this.http.get(tgtUrl, httpOptions).pipe(map((res: Response) => { //handle the response }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to append the headers directly to your request like this because `httpheaders` are immutable -

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('x-rapidapi-host', 'some value');
headers = headers.append('x-rapidapi-key', 'some value');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(
     {'Content-Type','application/json'},
     {'token', value});
     let httpOptions = { headers: httpHeaders};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @piedpiper @Sandeep and @nitish. I use a combination of all your suggestions.

```
    let httpHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    // let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(header);
    httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append("x-rapidapi-host", "some value");
    httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append("x-rapidapi-key": "some-value");

    this.appService.getData(this.apiUrl, httpHeaders, this.params ).subscribe(
      (data: any) => this.allData = data
```

And changed the getData code to

```
  getData(url: string, httpHeaders: HttpHeaders, params: object){
    console.log("header: "+ httpHeaders)

    console.log(this.http.get(url));
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: httpHeaders}); 
  }
```